Tomcat "not gzip format" install error in Eclipse
I am using Eclipse for an assignment for school through Codio. In this assignment i'm supposed to create a web service using Apache Tomcat ver 7 through Eclipse. However when installing Apache Tomcat in Eclipse I keep getting an error stating that it is not in GZIP format. As a result I can't install it.
Apache Tomcat Install Error:

I've tried different install directories and nothing has worked so far.

Which version of Eclipse is it? What version of Tomcat, and obtained from where/how? What are the full steps to reproduce?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is not an answer to your question but a suggestion to do you project a bit differently. Use Tomcat stand alone (consider using Tomcat 9 with JDK 17, if that is permissible), develop the application as a web application with JAX-RS (you could consider Jersey framework as JAX-RS implementation). Deploy the WAR file exported from eclipse in Tomcat and access it through Postman/browser. As for the error, my guess would be you are using .zip instead of tar.gz (just check once)
